# Using Request animation frame to animate Translate of a rectangle

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, requestanimationframe

First off I've created **[Live Code](http://codepen.io/matthewharwood/pen/pvameO?editors=001)**

**QUESTION:**

I can I make a **looping** animation of a rectangle being translate across the X coordinate?

**Problem:**

Currently, my animation only visibly happens once. The translation goes offscreen to be never seen again. Even tho the pos.x is being reset to zero.

```
(function(){
  var pos =  {x: 0, y:0};
  var c = document.getElementById('day1'),
      ctx = c.getContext('2d');

  function repaint(){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white'
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
  }

  function draw (){
    //paints over the last square otherwise this will create a ghost or tail effect
    repaint();
    //adds to 1 to translate or resets to 0
    if(pos.x <= 100){
              pos.x++;
    } else {
      pos.x = 0;
      //at the very least this should be drawing a new rect 1 pixel lower than the last
      pos.y++;
    }

    //paints the black rectangle 
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    //moves the position and animates till offscreen
    ctx.translate(pos.x, pos.y);
    ctx.fillRect(0,50,50,50);
    //watch the console.logs()
    console.log(pos);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  }

  draw();
})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `tranform()` is accumulative. Even when you reset `x` `transform()` will continue adding. You see this by the logarithmic increase in speed.

If you absolute want to use transforms then use `setTransform()` instead which allow you to set an absolute position.

Replace this line:

```
ctx.translate(pos.x, pos.y);
```

With:

```
// the two last arguments (e,f) are for translation
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, pos.x, pos.y);
```

Or just skip use of translation and draw your objects at x and y directly.

**[Updated pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPQePw)**

Answer (score 2):

The translate(x, y)-method moves the viewpoint of the **current** frame. The method doesn't reset the transformation matrix after rendering.
So if you want to move the rectangle one pixel per frame, you must call translate(1, 0) each frame. After 100 pixels you call translate(-100, 0), if you want to loop.

```
var xCounter = 0;
function draw()
{
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    if(xCounter <= 100)
    {
        ctx.translate(1, 0);
        xCounter++;
    }
    else
    {
        ctx.translate(-xCounter, 1);
        xCounter = 0;
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
draw();
```

I would avoid the translate-method:

```
function draw()
{
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    if(pos.x <= 100)
    {
        pos.x++;
    }
    else
    {
        pos.x = 0;
        pos.y++;
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillRect(pos.x, pos.y, 50, 50);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
draw();
```